# In android ListView last element is repeatedly showing

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom listview with two text fields. showing name and age.
I have given a sample array of three objects. but every time it is only showing the last element in the array for all positions of the `ListView`.

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.sridatta.listview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        details[] objects={new details("datta",19),new details("siva",20),new details("kd",18)};
     CustomArrayAdapter adapter=new CustomArrayAdapter(this,R.id.listtype,objects);
     ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

here is my Custom ArrrayAdapter class:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<details> {


public CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull details[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){Context context=getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_type,null);
        }
    TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);
    tv1.setText(getItem(position).name);
    tv2.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).age));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

here is details class

```
public class details {
static String name;
static int age;
public details(String name,int age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using recycling view, which will generate when android think you may see it on screen. For example, when scroll up, the last item may be hidden from screen, it will reuse the last item to show. And you only setText when initial the layout. You should change the code like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){Context context=getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_type,null);
    }
    //update the text when view show up
    TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.age); 
    tv1.setText(getItem(position).name);
    tv2.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).age));
    return convertView;
}
```

just notice your object class, you want them as different objects, but the static will meet their value to same memory position. you should remove the static in order to store them as unique object.

```
public class details {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public details(String name,int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

Comment: updated, the reason is the static of the detail class. By the way, in JAVA we used to use capital letter for class name, like Details instead of details